# Grab node without select (Cytoscape.js)

Tags: cytoscape.js

When I move a node with the mouse, it automatically becomes selected. I want the node to become selected only when I tap on it. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try playing with [autounselectify](https://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.autounselectify) You can set it to false and when tap happens, you can set it to true or etc.